# How do I trigger tinymce 4.x focus and blur events

Tags: tinymce, focus, blur

I realize that this question has been asked and answered several times, but I still can't make many of the solutions work. It seems like most of the discussions are older and maybe not compatible with 4.x.

My goal: be able fire some javascript functions upon focus or blur. Here's the base code:

```
$('.tiny-mce').tinymce({
    script_url : '/xm_js/tinymce4/tinymce.min.js',
});
```

I tried examples like:

```
$('.tiny-mce').tinymce({
    script_url : '/xm_js/tinymce4/tinymce.min.js',

    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {

        var dom = ed.dom;
        var doc = ed.getDoc();

            tinymce.dom.Event.add(doc, 'blur', function(e) {
                alert('blur!!!');
            });
        });
    }
});
```

returns:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined"

```
$('.tiny-mce').tinymce({
    script_url : '/xm_js/tinymce4/tinymce.min.js',
});

tinymce.activeEditor.on('focus', function(e) {
    console.log(e.blurredEditor);
});
```

returns: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined"
(but not sure if I have it in the right place)

```
$('.tiny-mce').tinymce({
    script_url : '/xm_js/tinymce4/tinymce.min.js',

    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('focus', function(e) {
            console.log('focus event', e);
        });
    }
});
```

returns: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

This works but only when initiating the editor. Other things I've tried but haven't gotten to work:

tinymce.FocusManager
tinymce.activeEditor

What am I missing? Thanks.

**UPDATE: found a solution that worked beautifully:** [Why TinyMCE get focus and blur event, when user jump from other input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695916/why-tinymce-get-focus-and-blur-event-when-user-jump-from-other-input-field/19670992#19670992)

Answer (score 10):

see the fiddle at http://fiddle.tinymce.com/8Xeaab/1

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editme",
    inline: true,
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('focus', function(e) {
            console.log("focus");
        });

        editor.on('blur', function(e) {
            console.log("blur");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Your cuestion title its about TRIGGERING focus and blur events, but you really are asking about HANDLING those events.
If anybody is still looking for triggering the events, the solution should by:

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: "#textarea_123",
        ...
     });
```

then, to set focus:

```
var inst = tinyMCE.EditorManager.get('textarea_123');
inst.focus();
```

Comment: Do you know what the corresponding function for blurring is?

Comment: Doesn't seems to have one. Maybe setting focus on anything else could help.
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/

Comment: If someone is still looking to trigger those event, in TinyMCE 4 and 5 there's a 'fire' method on the editor to do just that. myEditor.fire('blur') works just fine. https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#fire

Answer (score -1):

I recently ran into this issue and although I am doing this in angularjs I was able to implement a fix for it by creating a directive that registers when you click off of it and then clears the activeElement in the html body. I will add the directive below. You just call it on the object by adding click-off like you would an ng-cloak to a tag.

```
(function () {
  'user strict';

  angular.module('app.directives').directive('clickOff', ClickOff);

  function ClickOff($parse, $document) {
    var directive = {
      link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, $element, attr) {

      var fn = $parse(attr["clickOff"]);

      $element.bind('click', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      });

      angular.element($document[0].body).bind("click", function (event) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          $document[0].activeElement.blur();
          fn(scope, { $event: event });
        });
      });
    }
  }
})();
```