# TinyMCE - Check if the text is selected

Tags: javascript, tinymce, inline

I try to see if the TinyMCE inline editor is currently visible or the text is selected.

---

Solved.
Christoffer guided me to the right thing:

```
 <script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector:"textarea",
    setup: function(editor) {
      editor.on('focus', function() {
        console.log('focus');
      });
      editor.on('blur', function(){
        console.log('blur');
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```

More here: 
[Why TinyMCE get focus and blur event, when user jump from other input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695916/why-tinymce-get-focus-and-blur-event-when-user-jump-from-other-input-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get current selection from the active editor with:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
```

You can also loop all editors with something like:

```
for (edId in tinymce.editors) {
    if (tinymce.editors[edId].isDirty()) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

For more advanced control over when and if an editor is active you can setup callbacks to the init/focus and blur events in your editor init.

Comment: Thank you, you hinted me to the right thing! I have corrected my question.